# WinForms ComboBox: text vs. selectedtext

Tags: winforms, combobox

In my WinForms / C# application, I can choose either `Combobox.Text` or `Combobox.SelectedText` to return the string value of what's been selected. What's the difference, and when would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SelectedText is what's highlighted. Depending on the DropDownStyle property, users can select a part of the visible text.

For example, if the options are:

- Democrat
- Republican
- Independent
- Other

A user can select the letters "Dem" in Democrat - this would be the SelectedText.  This works with the ComboBoxStyle.Simple or ComboBoxStyle.DropDown, but NOT with ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList, since the third style does not allow selecting a portion of the visible item (or adding new items).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx

However, using the Text property, you can pre-select an option (by setting the Text to "Other", for example, you could select the last item.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx

Comment: Well now I feel like an idiot. My project only really ever uses combo boxes with DropDownList style, where you can't type or select text.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to see the difference using a text box:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Text in combo box 1";
        textBox2.Text = "Text in combo box 2";
        button1.Focus();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox2.SelectedText);
    }
```

In textbox2, select part of the text and click the button.

I've used this before for primitive spell checkers, when you only want to highlight part of the textbox (not the whole value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It helps when the DropDownStyle property is set to DropDownList.

```
public string GetProdName(int prodID)
{
    string s = "";
    try
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = cmng.GetDataSet("Select ProductName From Product where ProductID=" + prodID + "");
        if (cmng.DSNullCheck(ds) && cmng.DSRowCheck(ds))
        {
            s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
    return s;
}
```

In the click event:

```
lblProduct.Text = GetProdName((int)ddlProduct.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an item text which is in a combobox, you can use `[comboboxname].SelectedItem.ToString()`.

If you want to read an item value, use `[comboboxname].SelectedValue`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: if you want to read an item text which is in combobox, you can use [comboboxname].SelectedItem.ToString()
if you want to read an item value;
[comboboxname].SelectedValue